# Compress size of vuetify in production mode

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, production

i have project after production mode the size of app.js is 2.35 MB which is too large in production mode, it should be in KB?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you have `true` (which is default value in production mode) for `minimize` in webpack config according to the docs https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/ :

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimize: true
  }
};
```

**Upd.**

You can try to check if your css files is extracted from js-bundle. From here https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/199 :

> Probably cause you have CSS bundle in JS file, you can try
>   `build.extractCSS: true` in Nuxt options, it will separate Vuetify JS &
>   CSS. The CSS is by default kind of huge, but really smaller when using
>   gzip in production.

Comment: How ?? and my appliction is SPA

Comment: @ziakhan, I have made an update to my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: thanks brother i fixed,, by extract in laravel mix
Thanks a lot